# Connect to online Magento from a localhost

Tags: php, magento

Beside setting up a custom Magento API, is there a way to connect from a localhost webapp to an online Magento installation? More specifically, I'm looking for a setup that will allow me to write codes like

```
include('app/Mage.php');    // how does this work for online-offline connection??
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
```

in a webapp running on localhost in our office.

If this is not plausible, do I need to connect to the Magento store DB directly from my application and basically write my own queries? I would certainly create a new user with read-only access for the DB, if this was the case.

Comment: In order to use the `Mage` class you need to have Magento loaded (i.e. included `app/Mage.php`). If you want to use the Magento models and methods (as you've indicated in your code example) you will need to have the Magento source code.

Comment: Don't I need `app/Mage.php` of the instance on the server, though?

Answer (score 0):

No need to connect to the db the include will handle it:

```
require'app/Mage.php';  

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    Mage::log("Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.\n",null,'fiftyone_daemon.log');
    exit;
}
Mage::app('default'); 


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `require'app/Mage.php'` *not* work since I'm on localhost and I don't have the server files?